# Opening iBooks in iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ibooks

I want to open **.IBOOK file** in my application. My question is is it possible to do it cause my client want to make some iBooks using the iBook author and want to open them in Library Application which I am working on.
And If it is possible ***apple will approve this application*** or if there is any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you require is : [UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

iBooks has an undocumented URL scheme of ibooks, means you can launch iBooks with a URL like `[NSURL URLWithString:@"ibooks://"]`.

But I think, `UIDocumentInteractionController` is the correct way to do this. It is **the way Apple wants you to do it**. Plus, using `UIDocumentInteractionController` has the benefit of letting the user decide what to do with the file.

Comment: Thanks @Vin Actually I want to open .iBOOK file from my document directory. But in this example we are opening only PDF, txt etc. If we open . iBOOK file I hope Apple will not reject the application

Comment: do you know it it's possible to detect when the user has tapped on the external app? I mean, if it's an ibook with 500mb it takes a lot of time until it "jumps" to ibooks and the user doesn't see any progress until that actually happens